# zsh: How to check if an option is enabled

Tags: zsh

To enable an option, we can use `setopt`. e.g.:

```
setopt extended_glob
```

**How can we check if an option is currently enabled ?**

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In `zsh`, you can use `setopt` to show options enabled and `unsetopt` to show which are not enabled:

```
$ setopt
autocd
histignorealldups
interactive
monitor
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle

$ unsetopt
noaliases
allexport
noalwayslastprompt
alwaystoend
noappendhistory
autocd
autocontinue
noautolist
noautomenu
autonamedirs
.....
```

In `bash`, you can use `shopt -p`.

Comment: It should be noted that `setopt` only prints the options not enabled by default for that emulation mode.

Comment: You should use `set -o` for FULL list.

Comment: `set -o|sort` for zsh is good.

Answer (score 27):

Just use:

```
if [[ -o extended_glob ]]; then
  echo it is set
fi
```

That also works in `bash`, but only for the options set by `set -o`, not those set by `shopt`. `zsh` has only one set of options which can be set with either `setopt` or `set -o`.

Just like with `bash` (or any POSIX shell), you can also do `set -o` or `set +o` to see the current option settings.

Comment: What is small o flag `-o`? I read in `man test` ` -O FILE FILE exists and is owned by the effective user ID` which is  an upper O. Wait, in `man bash` I read `-o optname
True if the shell option optname is enabled.  See the list of options  under  the  description of the -o option to the set builtin below`. which should be it!

Answer (score 20):

The [`zsh/parameter`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) module, which is part of the default distribution, provides an associative array [`options`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-options-1) that indicates which options are on.

```
if [[ $options[extended_glob] = on ]]; then …
```

For options that have a single-letter alias (which is not the case of `extended_glob`), you can also check [`$-`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-_002d-1).

Note that it's rarely useful to test which options are enabled. If you need to enable or disable an option in a piece of code, put that code in a function and set the [`local_options`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-LOCAL_005fOPTIONS) option. You can call the [`emulate`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-emulate) builtin to reset the options to a default state.

```
my_function () {
  setopt extended_glob local_options
}
another_function () {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt extended_glob
}
```

Comment: Other than greater readability here, and greater brevity with the other one, is there any advantage one way or another between this and `if [[ -o extended_glob ]]; then...`?

Comment: @iconoclast Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only to check on terminal, I find the below helpful.

```
setopt | grep extended
```

Answer (score 0):

```
() {[[ -v argv[1] && -v options[$1] ]] && echo "option <$1> is $options[$1]" || echo "no such option <$1>"  } <optname>
```

With `<optname>` from https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html

Examples:

```
() {[[ -v argv[1] && -v options[$1] ]] && echo "option <$1> is $options[$1]" || echo "no such option <$1>"  } LOCAL_TRAPS

option <LOCAL_TRAPS> is off

() {[[ -v argv[1] && -v options[$1] ]] && echo "option <$1> is $options[$1]" || echo "no such option <$1>"  } localtraps
option <localtraps> is off

() {[[ -v argv[1] && -v options[$1] ]] && echo "option <$1> is $options[$1]" || echo "no such option <$1>"  } localtrap 
no such option <localtrap>
```